# I have some tables in my db and i want to delete this on click button which i select on the option tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some tables in my db and i want to delete this on click button which i 
       select on the option tag

```
    <?php 
  $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','post15');
  if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
  $query = $db->query("DELETE FROM posted WHERE title");
  if ($query) {
    echo "Post DELETED";
  }

 }?>
  <form method="post" action="admin.php">
     <select name="categoryBox">

            <?php 
                 $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posted");
                    while ($row = $query->fetch_object()){
                        echo "<option value='".$row->id."'>".$row->title."
              </option>";
                    }
            ?>

            </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit2">    
    </form>
```

Comment: Seems you have a worng where expression   .. If you want delete all  You should use   $query = $db->query("DELETE FROM posted ");

Comment: i dont want to delete all code,i want delete code which i select on option tag

Comment: then assign a valid value to there expressione eg: where title = 'my_tag';

Comment: `DELETE FROM posted WHERE title = ?` and to which it signifies using a prepared statement; which you should.

Comment: I seem to have understood the thought

Comment: this will never work, because the drop-down does not contain title but it contains id's

Comment: @НургисаАнуарбек is there a reason you accepted an answer and rejected it again?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will not work, you are trying to delete using a title but your drop-down option values are id's not titles therefore you should look at deleting the id of the selected title

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
  $query = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM posted WHERE id = ? ");
  $query->bind_param("i",$_POST['categoryBox']);
  if ($query->execute()) {
    echo "Post DELETED";
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this one.

```
  <form method="post">
Id: < input type="text" name="id">
<input  type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php 
$_POST['id']
$db=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("post15",$db);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM posted WHERE id=$id",$db);
echo"ID ".$_POST['id']." has been Deleted ";
?>
```